# Access parsed HTML when using MDX-JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

How can I access the HTML parsed from [MDX JS](https://mdxjs.com/getting-started/)

I have a simple setup:

`import Markdown from 'example.md'`

and in my React render method I can simply do:

```
render () {
  return <Markdown />
}
```

and it will render its contents as HTML just fine. But I would like to access this HTML before it's been rendered.

Is there any way to do so? I have tried

`console.log(Markdown.default)` but that does not work. Any way to access the HTML parsed by MDX JS?

Comment: maybe use another library then, like https://markdown-it.github.io/

Comment: @mb21 thanks for the idea but I specifically wanna use MDX because it comes with JSX support.